# PS Remoting failing: The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation."

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I am facing some issues while encrypting/decrypting on a remote machine. For ex: when i run the below commands i am getting the following error.

Can anyone know how to resolve this issue?

```
[remote machine]: PS C:\> Add-Type -assembly System.Security
[remote machine]: PS C:\> $passwordBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("Password!")
[remote machine]: PS C:\> $entropy = [byte[]](1,2,3,4,5)
[remote machine]: PS C:\> $encrytpedData = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect($passw
ordBytes, $entropy, "CurrentUser")
Exception calling "Protect" with "3" argument(s): "The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be tr
usted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation.
"
At line:1 char:71
+ $encrytpedData = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect <<<< ($passwordBytes, $entropy, "CurrentUser")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

regards,
naresh

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look to [Forwarding credentials in multihop environments](http://www.manning.com/payette2/SampleCh-13.pdf) in capter 13 of Bruce Payette nice book.

You perhaps need the CredSSP mechanism which enables you to securely pass your credentials to a target machine via a trusted intermediary.